# Load jenkins parameters from external groovy file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a big Jenkinsfile that I would like to re-use for other projects, but I have different parameters per project, so i've tried having one file per project containing only those parameters like this :

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node {

    checkout scm
    def options = []
    def optionsBuilder = load pwd() + '/global-scripts/optionsBuilder.groovy'
    options.addAll(optionsBuilder.buildOptions(env.JOB_BASE_NAME))


    properties { options }
}
```

**global-scripts/optionsBuilder.groovy**

```
def buildOptions(jobName) {
    echo "load " + pwd() + "/project-scripts/" + jobName + ".groovy"
    def jobOptionsBuilder = load pwd() + "/project-scripts/" + jobName + ".groovy"
    return jobOptionsBuilder.buildOptions()
}
return this
```

**project-scripts/job.groovy**

```
def buildOptions() {
    def options = [buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5')),
                   parameters([string(name: 'releaseVersion', defaultValue: env.releaseVersion, description: 'Version that needs to be released'),
                               string(name: 'nextVersion', defaultValue: env.nextVersion, description: 'Next snapshot version' ),
                               string(name: 'branch', defaultValue: env.branch, description: 'Branch that needs to be released'),
                               booleanParam(name: 'sendRocketChatNotification', defaultValue: true, description: 'Send notification to Rocket_Chat'),
                               booleanParam(name: 'sendEmail', defaultValue: true, description: 'Send an email with changelog'),
                               booleanParam(name: 'dryRun', defaultValue: false, description: 'No git push and no mvn deploy')])]


    return options
}
return this
```

But it seems i can't find the right syntax .. Jenkins throws me this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.JobPropertyStep.properties expects java.util.List<hudson.model.JobProperty> but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:394)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:318)
```

Comment: Why not try the Jenkins Shared Libraries option?

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy I'm discovering it right now, seems that it could solve some of my problems :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have the impression that in your Jenkinsfile you should just write

```
    properties(options)
```

Comment: This solved my problem .. I feel so stupid not having tried it :-)