# How can I reference my constant within a Jenkins Parameter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, class-constants

I have the following code in a `Pipelineconstant.groovy` file:

```
public static final list ACTION_CHOICES = [
    N_A,
    FULL_BLUE_GREEN,
    STAGE,
    FLIP, 
    CLEANUP
]
```

and this PARAMETERS in Jenkins multi-Rapper-file:

```
parameters {
    string (name: 'ChangeTicket', defaultValue: '000000', description : 'Prod change ticket otherwise 000000')
    choice (name: 'AssetAreaName', choices: ['fpukviewwholeof', 'fpukdocrhs', 'fpuklegstatus', 'fpukbooksandjournals', 'fpukleglinks', 'fpukcasesoverview'], description: 'Select the AssetAreaName.')
    /* groovylint-disable-next-line DuplicateStringLiteral */
    choice (name: 'AssetGroup', choices: ['pdc1c', 'pdc2c'])
}
```

I would like to ref `ACTION_CHOICES` in the parameter as this:

```
choice (name: 'Action', choices: constants.ACTION_CHOICES, description: 'Multi Version deployment actions')
```

but it doesn't work for me.

I tried to do this:

```
choice (name: 'Action', choices: constants.ACTION_CHOICES, description: 'Multi Version deployment actions')
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! Jenkinsfile(s) can be extended with variables / constants defined (directly in your file or (better I'd say) from a [*Jenkins shared library*](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) (this scenario).

The parameter syntax within you pipeline was fine as well as the idea of lists of constants, but what was missing: a proper interlink of those parts together - proper  library import. See example below *(the names below in the example are not carved in stone and can be of course changed but watch out - Jenkins is quite sensitive about filenames, paths, ... (especially in shared libraries])*:

`Pipelineconstant.groovy` should be placed in `src/org/pipelines` of your Jenkins shared library.

`Pipelineconstant.groovy`

```
package org.pipelines

class Pipelineconstant {
   public static final List<String> ACTION_CHOICES = ["N_A", "FULL_BLUE_GREEN", "STAGE", "FLIP", "CLEANUP"]
}
```

and then you can reference this list of constants within your Jenkinsfile pipeline.

`Jenkinsfile`

```
@Library('jsl-constants') _
import org.pipelines.Pipelineconstant


 pipeline {
    agent any   

    parameters {
        choice (name: 'Action', choices: Pipelineconstant.ACTION_CHOICES , description: 'Multi Version deployment actions')
    }

    // rest of your pipeline code

}
```

The first two lines of the pipeline are important - the first loads the JSL itself! Therefore the second line of that import can be used (otherwise Jenkins would not know where find that `Pipelineconstant.groovy` file.

---

**B) Without Jenkins shared library (files in one repo):**

I've found this topic discussed and solved for scripted pipeline here: [Load jenkins parameters from external groovy file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421047/load-jenkins-parameters-from-external-groovy-file)

Comment: Hi @David-kn Thanks a lot for your response . in my case we don't use a shared library , should I use package org when I have the constant file in the same folder as the multi-wrapper-pipeline?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see. Well, I'd still suggest / **recommend to at least consider using jenkins shared library** as it is a good possibility to have shared stuff (e.g. in your case parameters) for more pipelines.  
Otherwise, if from any reason you can't / decided not to, I've found such actually found a solution for scripted pipeline here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421047/load-jenkins-parameters-from-external-groovy-file